# How to blur text in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

The question is simple. I have a View with a Text component in it. I just want this text to be blurred initially.
The only solution I saw to blur something in React Native is for an Image via this "react-native-blur".

**How** can we **blur** a **Text** component in React Native?

Info: I just want to make an app where the user does not see the answer directly (via blurring).

Comment: `react-native-blur` should work as long as you use the `viewRef` prop and reference your `Text` component with it

Comment: Perhaps you can try putting a transparent image on the text and adjusting the `blurRadius` prop? I cannot test it now, so it's just a guess.

Comment: i think you can animate the text in textInput.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to install `react-native-blur` / `expo-blur` or it's not working for you, this is a workaround/hack that mimics the look of blurred text in a `View`. The values can be adjusted as necessary.

```
<View
  style={{
    height: 3,
    width: 70,
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 5,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
  }}
/>
```

Comment: seems like this is limited to fixed height and width. any idea how to make it work to dynamic width/height of child component?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use css to do it, feel free you change the amount of opacity, offset, color, radius as your requirement

```
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff0",
            textShadowColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
            textShadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            textShadowRadius: 10,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: "600",
            textTransform: "capitalize",
          }}
        >
         Blurred

        </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install react-native-blur:

npm install react-native-blur

```
import BlurView from 'react-native-blur';

...
<BlurView blurType="light" style={styles.blur}>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above replies, for iOS we can manipulate the text shadow to be visible and hide the actual text

```
const $shadowLyrics = {
  color: Colors.primary.solid,
  left: -2000,
  elevation: 2,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  shadowOpacity: 1,
  shadowRadius: 4,
  shadowColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
  shadowOffset: { width: 2000, height: 0 },
}
```

This ensures that we hide the text component and only show the blur, i.e
[Here's a reference Imgage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh5BQ.png) (you can play around with the width values to move the text away from reference)

However on Android, shadowOffset doesn't work as it does on iOS, but we can set the text colour to be transparent and the shadow to be the intended blur text colour (this doesn't work on iOS)

```
const $shadow = {
  color: "transparent",
  shadowOpacity: 1,
  textShadowRadius: 15,
  textShadowColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
}
```

[Android reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUWLu.png)