# Make text blurry in react-native

Tags: react-native

Just make the text blurry in react-native. Libraries, such as @react-native-community/blur turn images blurry flawlessly, but text doesn't work as expected, it creates a box around and does not blur the text.

The expected behaviour is like this

[Blurry Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLvpN.png)

Comment: There is an answer here, It's not accepted but might be work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422749/how-to-blur-text-in-react-native

Comment: That lib doesn't make the expected behaviour with text, but thanks @VolkanSahin45

Comment: have you found a solution @MatheusRobertLichtnow ?  I have the same requirement