# Make specific View / Text blur - React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, gaussianblur, react-native-blur

I want to make specific `View` blur in react native. I tried [react-native-blur](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur) but it is creating a rectangle box while is not looking good in case of `Text`. Also the result is not good in case of android. Desired result - Text blurrness

[image: blur text]

The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422749/how-to-blur-text-in-react-native) did not help.

Do you think react-native-svg can help? As `<Rect>` will still create reactangle box.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Svg, { Defs, Rect } from "react-native-svg";

const SVGComponent = (props) => (
  <Svg height={110} width={210} {...props}>
    <Defs></Defs>
    <Rect
      width={90}
      height={40}
      stroke="black"
      strokeWidth={3}
      fill="grey"
      filter="url(#f1)"
    />
  </Svg>
);
export default SVGComponent;
```

SVGR has dropped filter which not supported by react-native-svg. So, I am unable to find solution using RN-SVG. If anyone has any solution please discuss.